# Cannot instantiate the type MyWebViewClient

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

```
    package com.webview;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


    public class Webview_integrationActivity extends Activity {


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            mywebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());



        WebViewClient client = new MyWebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void launchExternalBrowser(String url) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(intent);
            }

        };
    }
    }


***************************************************************************************


package com.webview;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public abstract  class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.google.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

        launchExternalBrowser(url);    

        return true;

}

    public abstract void launchExternalBrowser(String url);



}
```

**I am getting the error as "Cannot instantiate the type MyWebViewClient" when I am running this program.I know that's because that class is abstract.But how to resolve my issue.I have pasted the code for both the classes that I am using.

Comment: I am doing this project for handling page Navigation so that the link opens within my webview.

Comment: I think you didn't read the whole code. I have used that.

Comment: please read the second class. after ******************************

Comment: my god.....your question is not formatted well actually. Nobody can see that code actually.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Webview_integrationActivity extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {



                          startActivity(new Intent(
                                       "android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                        Uri.parse("https://www.google.com")));
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          }

              });

    }
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.google.com")) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a right a way of increasing your reputation. What you did is, you just accepted my answer first then write you own code (using what I suggested you)in next FEW days and once done, posted your answer, unaccepted my reply and accepted your own answer. I guess this form should have blocked you.

Answer (score 0):

First : You can't instantiate an abstract class. you can only extend an abstract class.

Second : What is the need of creating your own WebViewClient class(MyWebViewClient). You can override shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) method using webViewClient in your main activity and does the same in this method that you are doing in launchExternalBrowser(String url) method.

I mean you are firing an intent inside launchExternalBrowser(String url) method which is getting called from shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) method. so  why don't you fire the same Intent inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) method itselft.

Comment: please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918108/progress-bar-not-working-webview-android